# Invalidate Browser cache for a single page

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, caching, browser

I realize a similar Q was asked 5 years ago. I'm hoping there may be a better answer today.

**Is there a programmatic way to tell a browser to expire its cached version of this page & to request a refresh from the server, next time?** Time based expiry is not fast enough.

**Requirement:** 
    I want the client to constantly reload the the page from its own cache, until I tell it (via SignalR) that the page is obsolete. Then if I could flush just-that-page from the local cache, the next time the user looked at it, it would pull the latest version from the server. So once more it would be cached locally.

**Why?** 
    The data on the page takes a long time to download & the javascript adds seconds to the render time. Often it remains static for 30 mins or more. But occasionally it changes a few times a minute. So a fixed time interval cache, doesn't work.

ASP MVC lets me invalidate the Output cache of a page on the server. Which is great. If I could do the same on the client it would be an awesome speed improvement.

Note: I'm not changing the CSS, Images or Javascript. I just want strip out a lot of JScript & to do most of the HTML rendering on the server, once per data change event.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar situation in my project where we wanted all clients to take latest version of files after each release. It was a simple spring MVC application. The fix we applied was we created a jsp tag which would add release number to all URL sent to server like:

```
www.abc.com/test.html/1
www.abc.com/test.html/2
```

Each time there is change in URL like this the browser does not uses cached copy but gets file from the server.

Release number you can keep in a config file and change after each release.